# understanding linux arguments and piping

Tags: linux, shell

So I'm trying to use the sh (Bourne Shell) to write some scripts. I keep running into this confusion. For the following:

```
1. rm `echo test`
2. echo test | rm
```

I know backticks are used to run the command first, okay.
But for piping in #2, why doesn't rm take in test as an argument? Is there something about piping I don't understand? I thought it was simply sending output of one command as the input to another.

And... related to my piping confusion maybe.

```
dir=/blah/blar/blar
files=`ls ${dir} -rt`
count=`wc -l $files` # doesn't work, in fact it's running it along with each file that exists
count2=`$files | wc -l` # doesn't work
```

How come I can't store the ls into "files" and use that?

Comment: As for your update, try listing the files and then piping that to `wc -l`.

Comment: i'm just wondering why i can't store that ls into a variable and use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use `xargs` there, as `rm` takes arguments to delete, it doesn't read from the `STDIN` (which is what pipes typically pipe).

```
echo test | xargs rm
```

The first one works because backticks are for substitutions, much like `${}` but not as easy. :)

Alternatively, you could use `find`.

```
find . -name test -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```

Comment: lol quick response, thanks. can i bother you with one more quick question. im going to post it right now

Comment: @dtc Sure, ask a new question and link me.

Comment: so it's probably a way of how wc handles inputs, so i might just be rushing the question instead of investigating it myself but i posted it in the same question

Answer (score 1):

In the first case the results of `echo test` (the string `test`) are being provided as a command-line argument to `rm`. In the second, the string `test` is being *piped* to the `stdin` file descriptor of the `rm` process. These are two very different things. Since rm doesn't read from stdin, it never sees `test`.